# Selector too complicated for Scrapy?

Tags: html, css, scrapy

I'm trying to get a CSS selector to work into Scrapy :

```
#product-details > div.price-sidebar.product-pricing.has-monthly-price > div.price-details.has-old-price
```

The problem is that Scrapy Shell doesn't work with this selector, I get nothing from it.
I've searched for an alternative but I can't find the information I need anywhere else.

How can I fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried slowly building up the selector - see what you get from #product-details then > div etc. At least you will be able to see at what point it breaks down. As you have not shown an example of what you are trying to scrape I don't think we can help further.

Comment: https://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/product/_apple-macbook-pro-13-2020-zilver-i5-16b-512gb-1661307.html   . This is the URL, I'm trying to get the offer section. It crashes at first div after #product-details

Comment: You can also try building selector automatically. In Firefox, for example, when you open "Inspect Element" (right click) and then right click on the corresponding HTML element you can do Copy -> CSS Selector. Then, by comparing them you can check what you're doing wrong when writing it by hand. I personally always use this and then simplify selector by hand, if possible.